# Adding data dynamically in javascript array

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have this controller:

```
public function main()
{
    $user=User::find(1);
    return view('home')->with('user',$user);
}
```

And in the `home.blade.php` view, i need to get the user's attributes travel, food, misc. I can get those using `$user->travel`, `$user->food`, `$user->misc` which are integers. 
but, i have to show these expenses in pie chart. So, i use [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/)

```
    Travel Expenses:{{$user->travel}}<br>
    Food Expenses:{{$user->food}}<br>
    Miscellaneous Expenses:{{$user->misc}}<br>

    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

    <script>
     var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var data = {
                labels: [
                    "Travel",
                    "Food",
                    "Miscellaneous"
                ],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        data: [300, 50, 100],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "#FF6384",
                            "#36A2EB",
                            "#FFCE56"
                        ],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: [
                            "#FF6384",
                            "#36A2EB",
                            "#FFCE56"
                        ]
                    }]
            };
        </script>
```

This will show static data 300,50, and 100. How can i add these data dynamically? I need `data: [300, 50, 100]`, to be something like `data: [$user->travel, $user->food, $user->misc],`

Comment: I don't know PHP but all you need to do is render them from your php server inline so i would guess [{{$user->travel}}, {{$user->food}}, {{$user->misc}}] directly in your javscript code, PHP will render the 300,50,100

Comment: Cleary I do know PHP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same notation:

```
data: [{{$user->travel}}, {{$user->food}}, {{$user->misc}}]
```

That way the template engine will render the values and when loaded in browser then javascript will use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that in your controller:

```
public function main()
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    $data = [
        'user'      => $user,
        'dataChart' => [$user->travel, $user->food, $user->misc]
    ];
    return view('home', $data);
}
```

and in your view:

```
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var data = {
    labels: [
      "Travel",
      "Food",
      "Miscellaneous"
    ],
    datasets: [{
        data: {{$dataChart}},
        backgroundColor: [
            "#FF6384",
            "#36A2EB",
            "#FFCE56"
        ],
        hoverBackgroundColor: [
            "#FF6384",
            "#36A2EB",
            "#FFCE56"
        ]
    }]
};
</script>
```

That's resolves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
<?php

$travel = $user->travel;
$food = $user->food;
$misc =  $user->misc;

$data = "[$travel,$food,$misc]";
?>

Travel Expenses:{{$travel}}<br>
    Food Expenses:{{$food}<br>
    Miscellaneous Expenses:{{$misc}}<br>

    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

    <script>
     var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var data = {
                labels: labels: [
                "Travel",
                "Food",
                "Miscellaneous",
                datasets: [
                    {
                        data: {{$data}},
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "#FF6384",
                            "#36A2EB",
                            "#FFCE56"
                        ],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: [
                            "#FF6384",
                            "#36A2EB",
                            "#FFCE56"
                        ]
                    }]
            };
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Travel Expenses:<span id='travel'>{{$user->travel}}</span><br>
 Food Expenses:<span id='food'>{{$user->food}}</span><br>
 Miscellaneous Expenses:<span id='misc'>{{$user->misc}}</span>

        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas> <script> 
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

        var data = { 
           labels: [
              "Travel", 
              "Food", 
              "Miscellaneous"
           ], 
          datasets: [ { 
             data: [
                document.getElementById('travel').innerHTML, 
    document.getElementById('food').innerHTML, 
    document.getElementById('misc').innerHTML],
             backgroundColor: [ "#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56" ], 
             hoverBackgroundColor: [ "#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56" ] 
           }] 
        }; 
    </script>


Try this.
```